# Client authentication and ACL permissions to znode of zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Client authentication  and ACL permissions to znode of zookeeper?

when client connect to zookeeper then create znode with ACL property (i.e Ids.AUTH_IDS) so now how authentication user only access to get the data form znode of zookeeper ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zookeeper command line:

you must execute "addauth" command first when you access to the path that has been setAcl.

```
addauth digest u1:p1
```

in zookeeper client
you must run addAuthInfo api first.

```
    try {
        ZooKeeper zk = new ZooKeeper("ip:2181", 10000, null);
        String auth = "u1:p1";
        zk.addAuthInfo("digest", auth.getBytes());
        zk.getChildren("/data", null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeeperException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```